# how can I rebuilt a sound filter based on the FIR coeficients known and nothing else?

Tags: python, signal-processing, digital-filter

I have a digital sound system able to let me export the FIR coefficients (501 taps) how can I identify the filter specifications?

I need a python routine to revert the coeficients for a filter specifications

Comment: What do you mean by filter specifications? In what format do you want to specify the filter, if not its impulse response?

Comment: yes, based on the FIR coeficientes for example draw the impulse response, Magnitude and phase!

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.freqz.html